# Firefox not displaying iFrame contents on jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

I've got a very odd situation happening. I'll give all I can to explain what's happening.

I've got a partial view that contains an iFrame. So on my main page, I make an ajax call to get the partial view.

main.cshtml:

```
<div id='reportPreviewDiv'></div>
```

partialview.cshtml:

```
<iframe id="testIFrame">
    This content is built with https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer/
</iframe>
```

main.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: reportUrl,
    data: { reportParameters: parameters },
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#reportPreviewDiv").html(data);

        // Function One
        $("#testIFrame").load(function () {
            // Do some extra stuff
            $("#reportPreviewDiv").show();
        });

        // Function Two
        $("#testIFrame").load(function () {
            // Do some extra stuff
        });
        $("#reportPreviewDiv").show();
    }
});
```

The goal is to wait until the iFrame is loaded before some other functionality takes place.

Function One works for IE and Chrome (which should look like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdOXy.png), but makes it look like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClVyU.png) in Firefox.

If I put

```
$("#reportPreviewDiv").show();
```

outside the .load() as it is in Function Two, it works fine for Firefox, but has a slight delay on Chrome and IE (as in it shows reportPreviewDiv before completing the functionality in the .load().

An extra piece of interesting is that I wrapped

```
$("#reportPreviewDiv").show();
```

in a setTimeout while outside the .load(), and when I set the timeout to any more than 1.5 seconds, it fails to show the content in the same manner as Function One.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `.show()` does not work all the time for Firefox.

Use this code to show the div:

```
$("#reportPreviewDiv").css('display', 'block');
```